# Оформление в диалоге перессказа другого разговора

Tags: пунктуация

Скажите,  пожалуйста, как оформить в диалоге пересказ другого разговора.
Например, правильно ли это?

– Тут я ему: « Ты что, магазин ограбил?» А он мне:«Знаешь, вчера я купил у них три булки. Пришел домой – а в пакете одна. Я вернулся. Они говорят: «Нехорошо», но меры не принимают, поэтому они как бы у меня в долгу». И тут в дверь стучат.

Спасибо заранее.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

— Тут я ему: «Ты что, магазин ограбил?» А он мне:(1) «Знаешь, вчера я купил у них три булки. Пришел домой,(2) а в пакете —(3) одна. Я вернулся. Они говорят: (4)"Нехорошо", но меры не принимают, поэтому они как бы у меня в долгу». И тут в дверь стучат.

Такой прием называется "прямая речь внутри прямой речи".
Правки:
(1). После двоеточия необходим пробел.
(2). Перед союзом **а** нужна запятая.
(3). Пропущено по контексту слово "только": ставить или не ставить тире — это дело авторского восприятия (есть пауза — ставим тире).
(4). Внутренние кавычки — *лапочки* ("...").

*А тот ему: «Этот дом наш общий»* (Ч.);
*А он: «Пошёл прочь, пьяная рожа!»* (М. Г.).

[§ 48. Прямая речь после слов автора (п. 2)](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=154#pp154)

Если прямая речь находится внутри слов автора, то перед ней ставится двоеточие, а после нее — запятая: *...потом сказал: «Да, так вот как», вздохнул, помолчал и ушёл* (А. Т.).
По условиям контекста: *Они говорят, но меры не принимают...*
[§ 51. Прямая речь внутри слов автора]

Пример:
*– Конечно. Ходили мы с ним на банкет, там издатели были и всякая такая публика… он сперва не хотел меня брать, а я ему: «Зря, что ли, я няню вызвала? Мне тоже пойти охота»… так вот, я сама слыхала, как Кристиан Фишер нашептывал Оуэну про то место – писательский дом отдыха. Потом спрашиваю у мужа: «Что это за местечко он тебе расписывал?» – а Оуэн мне: «Так я и сказал, жди! На то он и дом отдыха – от жены, от детей».*
[Р. Гэлбрейт. Шелкопряд](http://knijky.ru/books/shelkopryad?page=6)

Comment: Спасибо огромное.

Answer (score 2):

1. С абзаца.

«Спрашиваю его:

— Ты что, магазин ограбил?

А он мне:

— Знаешь, вчера я купил у них три булки. Пришел домой, а в пакете — одна. Я вернулся. Они говорят: "Нехорошо", — но меры не принимают, поэтому они как бы у меня в долгу.

И тут в дверь стучат.»

2. Строкой.

«Спрашиваю его: "Ты что, магазин ограбил?" А он мне: "Знаешь, вчера я купил у них три булки. Пришел домой, а в пакете — одна. Я вернулся. Они говорят: «Нехорошо», — но меры не принимают, поэтому они как бы у меня в долгу". И тут в дверь стучат.»